# Programmatically show volume dialog for all streams and keep it up

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

By using this

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

I can display the small system popup that shows the volume control on screen. Unfortunately, this command only shows one slider with the single stream that I indicate, and not all the other ones. In fact, this command popups the same dialog that is popped up when pressing a volume physical button. The popup stays alive for just 2 seconds. It's also possible to trigger the dialog with adjustVolume() and let the system decide which is the relevant stream, but still one only will be shown and for just 2 seconds.

During these 2 seconds the user is allowed to click the "v" button and enlarge the dialog, so that all the streams are available to be changed for a slightly longer time.

How can I programmatically trigger this *second* dialog, that displays all the available volume sliders, and keep it alive for a longer time (or let the user close it with back key)?